# Word describing windows that are too high to see the ground outside?

Tags: single-word-requests

There is a word, I believe it starts with a 'c', that describes windows whose function is to provide light or create a feeling of openness rather than to see outdoors because they are so high that seeing out of them isn't feasible. Here is a picture of a church containing windows of this type:

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are close.  You are thinking *clerestory*.

> In architecture, **clerestory** (/ˈklɪərstɔri/; lit. *clear storey*, also **clearstory**, **clearstorey**, or **overstorey**) are any high windows above eye level.
>
> <sub>http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clerestory</sub>

Comment: Dangit, you could have waited 15 seconds... ;-)

Comment: Wow, I expected that to take longer! Thank you very much, I've been trying to remember this for a while

Comment: Argh, now I'm going to have to start pronouncing it differently.  (On the infrequent occasions where I've seen it used, I've always read it as "cle-RESS-to-ree".)

Answer (score 0):

What about Skylight.

noun
noun: skylight; plural noun: skylights

```
a window installed in a roof or ceiling.
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skylight

Comment: Thanks, Neil, but I was looking specifically for the word 'clerestory'.